# CSS - multiple background image padding

Tags: css, background-image, background-position

I have a fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/jlnewnam/uXA4N/)...

I have multiple background images set in a `<div>`. However, it seems like relative positioning is all that's allowed.

Any possibility of padding these images, so they're not in the extreme corners? Simple div padding doesn't work.

```
.iso-container li   {
    background: #f8981d;
    background-image: url(http://webfro.gs/south/kb2/images/pdf-button.png), url(http://webfro.gs/south/kb2/images/bxw_email.png);
    background-position: bottom right, bottom left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: 10px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are OK with percentage positioning you could change your background-position to something like this:

```
background-position: 95% 95%, 5% 95%;
```

<kbd>[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcl64/uXA4N/1/)</kbd>

Comment: Very cool idea. Works great. 9 more minutes before I can accept.

Comment: Any idea how to add links to these?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the [four-value syntax](http://briantree.se/quick-tip-06-use-four-value-syntax-properly-position-background-images/) to give them offsets from any side if you need a little more precise control.